# Cant download any other app

Tags: applications, google-play-store, insufficient-memory

My ocean t1 can't install any app except Facebook and whatsapp.
It says i have insufficient memory every time i try to install another app yet it has RAM of 1.1GB and ROM 8GB
I wonder why?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already checked with our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](/tags/insufficient-memory/info)?

Answer (score 0):

If it's about installing, then ram got nothing to do with it. If it was about opening after installing, then yes, ram could be a problem. You mentioned that you had 8 GB of space, which I could see be the problem. 8 GB space is just not enough today. Even 16 gb struggles to barely install some apps after the OS has been installed.